# Formas de crear un ListBox con fondo transparente

Tags: c#, windows-forms, listbox

Antes de nada he de decir que ya he creado un `ListBox` con fondo transparente gracias al aporte de otra persona [en el foro inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207186/custom-listbox-with-transparent-backcolor-issue).

El problema es que aun habiendo obtenido el resultado que buscaba no estoy contento con la "chapuza" que he hecho en el código y me gustaría saber si se puede hacer de otra manera o cierro el .cs y no lo miro más en todo lo que me quede del proyecto.

Si a alguno/a le sirve este código es libre de replicarlo o hacer lo que quiera con el (puede que os de fallo la fuente ya que es una que yo instalé):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RetroGameManager
{
    public partial class CustomListBox : ListBox
    {
        public CustomListBox()
        {
            Font = new Font("Orbitron", 11.25F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
            ScrollAlwaysVisible = false;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                     ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                     ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255);
        }

        protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Site != null)
                return;
            if (e.Index > -1)
            {
                string item = Items[e.Index].ToString();
                SizeF sf = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item, Font, Width);
                e.ItemHeight = Font.Height + 2;
                e.ItemWidth = Width;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Site != null)
                return;
            if (e.Index > -1)
            {
                string item = Items[e.Index].ToString();
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) != 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
                    {
                        X = 0,
                        Y = 0,
                        Width = Width,
                        Height = e.Bounds.Top
                    };
                    Invalidate(rect);
                    rect.Y = e.Bounds.Bottom;
                    rect.Height = Height - rect.Y;
                    Invalidate(rect);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0)), e.Bounds);
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach(string item in Items)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, (Font.Height + 2) * count++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El efecto que crea es este: [image: ListBox]

Comment: Esto es winforms no? porque en wpf seria muchisimo mas simple.. la recomendacion seria que si funciona, no lo mires mas..

Comment: Si, es winforms, se me olvidó ponerlo en las etiquetas. Intenté hacerlo la primera vez con wpf pero al no tener conocimientos de como modificarlo hice este apaño.

Comment: Pero son dos cosas muy distintas.. o sea.. cambiaste todo el entorno de tu proyecto por este problema? tienen funcionalidades muy distintas tambien....

Comment: viste esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658282/73749, ni lo probe, pero creo que era algo muy simple en wpf...

Comment: En realidad no, hice el proyecto improvisando y una vez terminado empecé a ver que cosas podria mejorarle, este listbox es una de esas mejoras por ejemplo.

Comment: no flashea mucho la pantalla con este codigo?

Comment: Precisamente ese fue el código que probé pero al añadirlo al form me daba el error `El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: objecType`.

Comment: No flashea debido a que tiene `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` como flags en el SetStyle, que primero crea la imagen en un buffer y luego la pone en la pantalla principal quitando el parpadeo.